# service fabric local cluster exception from 0x80071BFF

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created a solution with a few applications, and it worked perfectly. But a day later when I was about to debug the solution again, it suddenly cannot start.
I did have firewall and AV disabled, both when it worked and later when it didn't work.
It works fine when deployed to azure, but not locally.

The error thrown is:

Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BFF

```
    at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeRuntime.FabricGetNodeContext()
   at System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.NativeFabricRuntimeFactory.GetNodeContextHelper()
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag, String functionArgs)
```

A related post [register-servicefabricapplicationtype-on-a-secure-cluster-always-times-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119341/register-servicefabricapplicationtype-on-a-secure-cluster-always-times-out)

describes a similar thing.
However, I get this while debugging locally and with smallest possible application: I even just created 1 application, 1 actor, did no changes, hit F5 and I get this error.

So, I looked at [service-fabric-troubleshoot-local-cluster-setup](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-troubleshoot-local-cluster-setup/) and while I also get the TypeInitializationException, the solution of:

```
Your path variable was not correctly set during installation. Please sign out of Windows and sign back in. This will fully refresh your path.
```

did not work at all.
Nothing else on that page seemed to be related.

Now I begin to feel that I've hit the end of what key words I can google, and still I have no idea what to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I've tried starting via cluster manager and apps can still not start.
I've removed apps, removed cluster, tried with new solutions, over and over. The only thing I haven't tried is reinstalling SDK and VS. I'm a bit reluctant to reinstall VS, so I'd hope to find some clues before resorting to that.

**UPDATE1:**
Now I reinstalled Service Fabric v. 5.3.311.9590, SDK and Tools.
Created a solution, added a stateless service. Hit F5. The exact same error is thrown.
I will now try to install on another machine with mostly the same configuration.

**UPDATE2:**
Installed the SDK on an identical VM, Win10, also with VS2015 Update 3. Created solution, added 1 actor, hit F5 and also on this macchine the exact error is thrown.
I tried Debug without debugging (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068045/cannot-debug-project-after-upgrading-to-service-fabric-sdk-v2-3-301)) to attach later. But the application never starts. It is failed. This is the same on both the machines.

It all worked and from one day to the other it doesn't, and it's a problem that I cannot find anywhere on the net. What can this be? I found that the security updates from windows was made about the same date this happened...
I will uninstall and try again.

**UPDATE3:**

Uninstalling security update was not possible, but I could hide a couple of other updates. To no luck though.
From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892366/partition-is-below-target-replica-or-instance-count-error-after-deploying-serv?rq=1) I found this https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/15 and realised I actually was very low on diskspace, and so I increased it (hyper-v manager) to 20 gigs free. But no, still the same problem.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem, where you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: I did a new VM with win10 and vs15 and it solved the problem. Here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/92 I wrote about it and there was a comment saying: "I looked at the traces, and the issue here is that the security negotiation is timing out which we typically see in heavily loaded machines. ..." Go to the link for more details.
I don't know if that was actually a solution though.